# Export TIN mesh with QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, tin, mesh

I realized a TIN mesh from isoipse with QGIS. I would like to export it, but the problem is that I can't export the file.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Please edit your question to specify what you want to output to and what you have tried.